closed-form eigen-decomposition of $\operatorname{diag}(a_1, \dots, a_d) + v v^\mathsf{T}$
what have i learned: Eigenvalues of $I + v v^T$
i want to generalize from $\color{red}{\mathbf{I}_d + v v^\mathsf{T}}$ to $\color{blue}{\operatorname{diag}(a_1, \dots, a_d) + v v^\mathsf{T}}$, where $\operatorname{diag}(a_1, \dots, a_d)$ is a diagonal matrix, whose diagonal elements are $a_1, \dots, a_d$ and other elements are $0$, i.e.
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_d \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where $\forall i \in [d]$, $a_i > 0$.
(maybe it helps to assume $\forall i \in [d-1]$, $a_{i+1} > a_i$.)

edit#1
thanks to Theo Bendit, Thorsten Raasch, Ben Grossmann, and Paul Sinclair, i see that it is impossible to get any closed-form eigen-related result from the generalized problem $\mathbf{A} + u u^\mathsf{T}$ unless (the direction of) $u$ coincides with one of the eigen-vectors of $\mathbf{A}$.
note that if $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^\mathsf{T}$, then $\mathbf{A} + u u^\mathsf{T} = \mathbf{Q} \left( \mathbf{\Lambda} + (\mathbf{Q}^\mathsf{T} u) (\mathbf{Q}^\mathsf{T} u)^\mathsf{T} \right) \mathbf{Q}^\mathsf{T}$, set $v := \mathbf{Q}^\mathsf{T} u$, the problem $\mathbf{A} + u u^\mathsf{T}$ is reduced to the problem $\operatorname{diag}(a_1, \dots, a_d) + v v^\mathsf{T}$.
however, as Ben Grossmann mentioned, it is possible to perform efficient rank-one eigen-decomposition update. given the eigen-decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$ as a warm start, it is always easier to eigen-decompose $\mathbf{A} + u u^\mathsf{T}$.
related papers: (copied from this mo post)

Golub, G. H. (1973). Some modified matrix eigenvalue problems. SIAM review, 15(2), 318-334.
Bunch, J. R., Nielsen, C. P., & Sorensen, D. C. (1978). Rank-one modification of the symmetric eigenproblem. Numerische Mathematik, 31(1), 31-48.

related formulas: (copied from this mo post)

Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula
Sherman–Morrison formula / Woodbury matrix identity

thanks for your comments!

edit#2
hi guys, i just found something that might be useful from the paper by Golub. briefly speaking, the eigen values after the rank-one update could be bounded by the eigen values before the rank-one update.
here is a screenshot of the related content from the paper by Golub:

(which turns out to be a special case of Weyl's inequality.)

I will say, this is unlikely to yield anything nice. The $I + vv^\top$ case works works because $I$ has the lovely property that every subspace is invariant. Adding it to any square matrix will therefore not change the eigenvectors (and will add one to the eigenvalues). None of this can be said for an arbitrary diagonal matrix. I doubt that there's a method more efficient than just going ahead and calculating as you would a general matrix.

See this MO post

In short, you won't find any closed form decomposition. The best you can do is find relatively efficient algorithms for computation.

If matrices $C = aA + bB$ with non-zero scalars $a,b$, and if $A,B$ share an eigenvector $v$, with eigenvalues $\alpha, \beta$ respectively, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $\gamma = a\alpha + b\beta$.  Since $B$ can also be written as linear combination of $A$ and $C$, we see that the only way for $A$ and $C$ to share an eigenvector is when $B$ has it as well. The other post works because every vector is an eigenvector of $I$, so $I +vv^\top$ has the same eigenvectors as $vv^\top$ itself: the line of $v$ with e.v. $|v|^2$ and its normal hyperplane with e.v. $0$.

The problem is trivial if $v=e_k$ is a unit vector: In that case,
$$\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_d)+vv^\top=\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1},a_k+1,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_n)$$
is a diagonal matrix with its eigenvalues on the main diagonal, and with the unit vectors as eigenbasis.
But if $v$ is not a unit vector and if the $a_k$ are distinct, the matrices $\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_d)$ and $vv^\top$ will in general not commute, so that their sum will have a completely different eigensystem.
